# Long-running blocking task with Akka's actor

Tags: scala, akka

I want one of my Akka actors to perform long-running blocking task (finding a substring in a very long string, as an example). How should I do this following actors' phylosophy (not blocking other actors etc.)?

I'm thinking about running this actor in a separated thread with `PinnedDispatcher`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If this computation will run on its own execution context, meaning different dispatcher, and be wrapped in `future` I think you can't do anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the call in a Future

Comment: And if I want to send message with the result of computations, I can set `onComplete` callback on the future, right?

Comment: You can fold over the sender of the message and send then a response when the future completes. However you have to be careful and make sure you assign the sender to a local val before you execute the future. You then send your response back to this local copy rather than the original sender

Comment: I would give a code example but I'm in hospital waiting for my girlfriend to give birth and I'm doing this on my phone. Basically you should google and read about the risks of folding over mutable state in actors

Comment: Thank you, @bobbyr , I've understood the idea.

Comment: If you just want to send the result to the sender, use `pipeTo`.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the task in a future and send the result to the other Actor using the `pipe` pattern. The other actor will receive either the resulting value or an `akka.actor.Status.Failure` holding the cause.
If you want to respond to the sender it would be:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

def receive: Receive = {
  case msg =>
    val future: Future[String] = Future(longRunningBlockingTask(msg))
    future pipeTo sender
}
```